# How to reverse 1000 so that the output will be 1 (not 0001) using recursion or else normal in JAVA

Tags: java

As I have already made the code just I have to add the required condition(1000 == 1 ! 0001). Can anybody help me out.

```
public class ReverseNum {

    static void reverseInteger(int n) {
        // Write your code here

        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.print("-");
            reverseInteger(n * -1);
        } else if (n < 10) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(n % 10);
            reverseInteger(n / 10);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = s.nextInt();
        reverseInteger(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: A good first step would be to not print immediately every character you handle but to build a string, check it has no leading 0s and *then* print it when you're done.

Comment: Also, I guess this is homework and the fact the solution is recursive is mandatory? Or is it not?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with negative numbers: they need special consideration (and also will break string reversal and parsing).

A solution that works with any int:

```
public static int reverse(int value) {
    if (value < 0) {
        // special handling for negative numbers
        return 0 - reverse(-value);
    }
    int reversed = 0;
    while (value > 0) {
        reversed = reversed * 10 + (value % 10);
        value /= 10;
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Test cases:

```
assertEquals(0, reverse(0));
assertEquals(321, reverse(123));
assertEquals(98765, reverse(567890000));
assertEquals(-91, reverse(-19));
assertEquals(-2, reverse(-20000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
private static int reverseInteger(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return n;
    }
    int symbol = n / Math.abs(n);
    n = Math.abs(n);
    String str = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(n)).reverse().toString();
    return symbol * Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

Test cases:

```
@Test
public void test_reverseInteger() {
    assertEquals(0, reverseInteger(0));
    assertEquals(321, reverseInteger(123));
    assertEquals(98765, reverseInteger(567890000));
    assertEquals(-91, reverseInteger(-19));
    assertEquals(-2, reverseInteger(-20000));
}
```